# jQuery Rotate and container dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jQuery rotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) plugin to rotate an image. The problem is that when the image rotates it comes out of the boundry of the container as the width and height of the container are not updated.

Is there away to update the container dimensions also? If you want to look at the application you can [go here](http://bit.ly/1393PVP). Upload an image and press rotate to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback function which will be called when the animation is done.. In this function you can reset the img container width and height like this (not tested):

```
var img = $('#img');
var cont = img.parent();
img.rotate({bind:{
      click: function(){
          $(this).rotate({
            angle: 0, 
            animateTo:180,
            callback: function(){
                cont.css({ width: img.css('height'), height: img.css('width') });
            }
          })
      }
  }
});
```